# why when i create google storage bucket it will remind me the buck name exists?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-translation-api

when i create google storage bucket in my own google account, some name i put it will reminds the name already exists.

Is there only one namespace for create bucket and the bucket name not bind to user account?

It seems strange, only have one namespace.

Answer (score 0):

GCS buckets are in a global namespace:

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/naming-buckets#considerations